# A generic C++ rule engine comparing 2 String Maps

Tags: c++, rule-engine

I want to check if there are any components out there that can get me a basic rule engine. The engine should be able to take in a Rule string which will be basic logical rule which will return either TRUE or FALSE. It should take in an string map for inputs and string map for comparison purposes.

Example1 :

```
I want to check if the Object is of type "Apple"
The text rule would say "OBJECT_TYPE=="FRUIT" & FRUIT_TYPE=="Apple""
If Input is MAP1 ==> { (OBJECT_TYPE->FRUIT),(FRUIT_TYPE->Apple) }
        MAP2 ==> NULL 
Output should be TRUE

If Input is MAP1 ==> { (OBJECT_TYPE->FRUIT),(FRUIT_TYPE->Orange) }
        MAP2 ==> NULL 
Output should be FALSE
```

Example2 :

```
I want to check if the Object is of type "Apple" and group with size
The text rule would say "OBJECT_TYPE=="FRUIT" & FRUIT_TYPE=="Apple""
If Input is MAP1 ==> { (OBJECT_TYPE->FRUIT),(FRUIT_TYPE->Apple), (SIZE->BIG) }
        MAP2 ==> {(SIZE==BIG)}
Output should be TRUE

If Input is MAP1 ==> { (OBJECT_TYPE->FRUIT),(FRUIT_TYPE->Apple), (SIZE->SMALL) }
        MAP2 ==> {(SIZE==BIG)}
Output should be FALSE
```

The idea is to compare 2 maps according to a logical rule and return TRUE or FALSE. It should also support arithmetic logic like weight > 50 in rules and so the same check with the input map. The output of the system can be something like TRUE, FALSE, INPUT MAP Not fully populated, Error in Rule etc.

Does anyone know if some Opensource already provides this type of a functionality?

Comment: so map2 contains additional conditions already in map form? or what exactly is its purpose? This all sounds like a very specific problem description. I doubt that there is an existing software which will adher to that exact specification

Comment: Yes. Map2 contains additional variables to compare. The idea is to compare 2 maps to a logical rule. I can write my own parser but I am not completely sure whether I can handle all the arithmetic and logical components of it. Just checking if there is something generic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is no. Your situation is too specific, so you probably should write your owen components. In my experience, you can write a grammer parser, boost.spirti maybe a good partner.